# Submitted react stateful form with Netlify always return 404

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify

I've created a form using React and Bulma. Now I wanted to incorporate Netlify and just use their form handling. I've included 'data-netlify'='true' and 'data-netlify-honeypot'='bot-field' and used their suggested way of incorporating the fetch request onSubmit. But I always return a 404 on submit and I don't know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried all the steps that Netlify has suggested. At least I think I have.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';
import '../css/ContactFormAndFooter.css';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faUser, faEnvelope, faPhone } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const encode = (data) => {
return Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join("&");
}

class ContactInfoForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      'name': '',
      'email': '',
      'phone': '',
      'details': ''
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({ "form-name": "contact", ...this.state })
    })
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          name: '',
          email: '',
          phone: '',
          details: ''
        });
        alert('Success!');
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error));

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const { name, email, phone, details } = this.state;
    return (
      <section className='section contact-section'>
        <Fade left>
          <h3 className='title is-3'>Please introduce yourself and tell me a little bit about your project</h3>
        </Fade>
        <Fade right>
          <div className='container is-centered card box contact-container'>
            <form 
              name='contact' 
              method='POST' 
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
              data-netlify-honeypot='bot-field' 
              data-netlify='true'
            > 
              <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
              <p className="hidden">
                <label>Don’t fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" /></label>
              </p>
              <div className='field'>
                <div className='control has-icons-left'>
                  <input 
                    className='input has-text-weight-light' 
                    name='name' 
                    type='text'
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    placeholder='First and Last Name' 
                  />
                  <span className='icon is-small is-left'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} style={{'color':'#4B0082'}} />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='field'>
                <div className='control has-icons-left'>
                  <input 
                    className='input has-text-weight-light' 
                    name='email' 
                    type='email' 
                    value={email}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    placeholder='Email' 
                  />
                  <span className='icon is-small is-left'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} style={{'color':'#4B0082'}} />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='field'>
                <div className='control has-icons-left'>
                  <input 
                    className='input has-text-weight-light' 
                    name='phone' 
                    type='number' 
                    value={phone}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    placeholder='Phone Number'
                  />
                  <span className='icon is-small is-left'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} style={{'color':'#4B0082'}} />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='field'>
                <label className='label has-text-grey-light has-text-weight-light'>Project Description</label>
                <div className='control'>
                  <textarea 
                    className='textarea' 
                    name='details' 
                    value={details} 
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="control has-text-centered">
                <button className='button has-text-white' type='submit'>Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default ContactInfoForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 almost certainly occurs because the form has not been detected by Netlify.  Netlify returns an HTTP 404 status for ALL `HTTP(s) POST` operations EXCEPT ones that are either [proxy'd](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) to another site [or function](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/) (then we proxy the POST) OR requests that match a URL we are expecting a POST to - one we've been notified at deploy time will be the endpoint for form submissions.

How to notify Netlify that an endpoint is intended for form submissions?  This situation usually happens because you have no plain-html form definition or it doesn't include the `netlify` or `data-netlify=true` form parameter in the html `<form ...>` definition, which is what we parse to discover the endpoint.  We don't parse javascript, only html.  Some frameworks (I thought React was one, but your usage may not lead to this) will create html files from your JS and deploy those and we'll parse those.  You might want to download a copy of your deploy to confirm that there is a plain-html version of your form with the endpoint you are trying to post to (`action=` parameter) specified.  The below screenshot shows the icon to download a copy of your deploy from any successful deploy's logs page:

[image: screenshot of deploy logs page with download icon highlit]

Comment: thanks for response but it didn't fix it. I downloaded the files and it doesn't look like its creating a static form I think. But I did follow both this [page](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/?_ga=2.67055465.612206507.1545853697-1429025568.1545399884) and this [blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) to try and figure it out. I'm not sure what I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: wasn't intended to solve the problem, only to illustrate the problem you need to solve - making sure there is a static form there :)  You could create one by hand as plain html that isn't linked to with the exact same form-name and fields, and then your JS form will work.  Since it's not there - the JS form couldn't work, for the reason I described:  we don't parse JS looking for forms and we don't accept POSTs to forms we haven't parsed

Comment: that fixed my problem! I created a plain html form and that worked. Sorry I'm still a little confused though about why that works? Just creating a static html form works? I know you said netlify doesn't parse JS but I'm just still lagging behind about how just adding hidden form now makes my react form work. But thank you for helping me fix my problem.

Comment: Netlify requires an html version of a form to enable it.  Some frameworks (as I mentioned, I thought react was one, but it seems not to have been for you) automatically render your JS to html during build so Netlify sees that "rendered" html form.  Your framework/build pipeline does not seem to do that, so Netlify didn't see your form at all until you "faked one up" for Netlify to process.  Netlify's processing of the HTML form configures the service to allow form submissions.